# Getting error in imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

I am running a simple string to compare screenshot but i am getting an error
Error : 0x80041771
Code  : 80041771
Source : ImageMagickObject.MagickImage.1
I am still getting output but my script got halted due to above error

```
Option Explicit
Sub Compare_Image()

Dim img
Dim msgs
Set img = CreateObject("ImageMagickObject.MagickImage.1")
msgs = img.Composite("C:\Users\manasm\Desktop\test\osd4_1.bmp", 
"C:\Users\manasm\Desktop\test\osd4_sm.bmp", "-compose", "difference", 
"C:\Users\manasm\Desktop\test\DIFFBLOCK.bmp")
Set img=Nothing
WScript.Quit(0)
End Sub
```

Please give some clue